# How to create a file with todays date in the filename

Tags: linux, bash

Command 1:

```
$ touch test"date"
```

Command 2:

```
$ date +"%F"
2018-01-16
```

I want to be able to run the command so the file `test_2018-01-16` is created. **How do or can I combine the 2 commands above to do this?**

```
$ touch test_"date"
```

---

### EDIT1 - Answer

tks

these commands

```
touch fred-`date +%F`
touch "test-$(date +%F)"
touch "test2_$(date +"%F %T")"
```

prduce the following files respectively

```
fred-2018-01-16
test-2018-01-16
test2_2018-01-16 11:51:53
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should use double quotes and need to evaluate `date +"%F"` using [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).

```
  $ touch "test_$(date +%F)"
```

This will create an empty file `test_2018-01-15`

Double quote helps you create a single file where some options of `date` command would include a space.

For example, `touch test_$(date)` will create multiple files, where as `touch "test_$(date)"` won't.

As pointed out by OP, one would need additional quotes `"` around the format options, when multiple of them are used:

```
touch "test_$(date +"%F %T")"
```

Comment: Actually you don't.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the answer ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong either actually.

Comment: "Don't need double quotes" (in this very specific case), maybe?

Comment: The original answer just said "You need double quotes" and no other explanation. It is all fixed now.

Comment: Consider quoting the format string as well (I know it doesn't matter here) :)

Comment: @PesaThe You don't need additional quotes around the format options because they are covered under the quotes around the filename. Do you see an edge case that I don't see ?

Comment: Careful here, `$()` creates a new quoting context. Try this: `touch "test_$(date +%F %T)"` :)

Comment: Is this `date +%F %T` even a valid syntax. I am using GNU date and it gives me error. If you are talking about `date +%F +%T`, there can't be a space between the format options without quoting them around. This answer doesn't cover how one should execute the `date` command correctly.

Comment: Ah, that's what I meant. To quote the string like this: `touch "test_$(date +"%F %T")"`. It is not needed in this case. But shows to OP how easily he can add format strings with spaces. Which I think might come in handy since OP didn't know how to use command substitution :) it's up to you of course.

Answer (score 4):

In my world (with Bash) its:

```
touch fred-`date +%F`
```

where 'fred-' is the prefix and teh date command provides the suffix